# How to convert frequency table into trend analysis graph

Tags: r

I have a frequency table.

```
> mytable <- table(substring(ukaccidents$Date, 7, 10), ukaccidents$Accident_Severity)
> mytable

        Fatal Serious Slight
  2005   2913   25029 170793
  2006   2926   24946 161289
  2007   2714   24322 155079
  2008   2341   23121 145129
  2009   2057   21997 139500
  2010   1731   20440 132243
  2011   1797   20986 128691
  2012   1637   20901 123033
  2013   1608   19624 117428
  2014   1658   20676 123988
  2015   1616   20038 118402
  2016   1695   21725 113201
  2017   1676   22534 105772
  2018   1671   23165  97799
```

How do show this table as a trend analysis graph in ggplot (x axis = Date, y axis = AccidentSeverity)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a neat solution using reshape2:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

df <- as.data.frame(mytable)
df <- setNames(melt(df)[,-3], c("Year", "Severity", "Accidents"))
ggplot(df, aes(Year, Accidents, fill = Severity)) + geom_col()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>